# How to escape quotes for remote command via ssh command line

Tags: python, linux, awk, command, escaping

I'm having trouble issuing the following command on remote server. The | awk '{print $1}' did not appear to have any effect on the output. Am I incorrectly escaping the quotation characters? To make it worse, these two commands are actually submitted via a python script... thus making escape just more confusing...

On local server:

```
ssh remote.server.com "find /root/directory -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}'"
```

On remote server:

```
find /root/directory -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
In yourscript line 1:
ssh remote.server.com "[...] | awk '{print $1}'"
                                           ^-- SC2029: Note that, unescaped, this
                                                       expands on the client side
```

There you go. You can escape it with a backslash.

Answer (score 4):

You can either escape `$1` as `\$1` Or run awk locally:

```
ssh remote.server.com "find /root/directory -type f -exec md5sum {} +" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Result should be the same.